# .NET datatable to a temporary SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable, sql-server-2008-r2

What would be the fastet and most efficient way to put a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) in .NET into a temporary SQL table on a remote [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) instace?

The datatables I am working on can contain up to 100,000 records, so I am concerned about performance.

Comment: you have to use the [Paging](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/harabchuk/Paging%20in%20MS%20SQL%20using%20ROW_NUMBER())

Comment: @spajce No, he  does not. Especially not for loading. I suggest you get an hour or so practice with sql server before giving irrelevant advice. He is uploading TO the server, and even if he would download - if you need all the data, only someone with no clue would use paging instead of a straight SQL statement.

Comment: wow.. i love this, thank so much for that info sir. i will note that `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100k records and you are comcerned about performance? Is the server a mobile phone? 1 million records is SMALL, 100 million starts to be "think or you have a problem" level, 100.00 records is something my tablet can efficiently deal with.

Just do it. SqlBulkCopy is the fastest way to move data from a .NET application down to a server and there is not a lot you CAN optimize anymore after using that. I regularly upload millions (tens of millions) of records doing that my grid does financial simulations.